# query json array having only strings oracle

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c, exists

Below is the json stored in a table called "Sample" and the column name is "argument". I want to fetch all those records having a particular value in a specified argument. I could query the argument name but not able to query a particular value as it is an array of strings. (Please find my keys have . in it)

```
{
 "arguments":{
    "app.argument1.appId":["123", "456"],
    "app.argument2.testId":["546", "567"]
 }
}
```

This gives me all the records having particular argument.

```
 select * from sample where json_exists(argument, '$.arguments."app.argument1.appId"');
```

But I need to match argument value. I tried below but getting JSON expression error.

```
select * from sample where json_exists(argument, '$.arguments."app.argument1.appId[*]"?(@ == "123"));
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the quotation marks in the wrong place; you want the double quotes before the square-brackets for the array instead of afterwards:

```sql
select *
from   sample
where  json_exists(
         argument,
         '$.arguments."app.argument1.appId"[*]?(@ == "123")'
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample ( argument CLOB CHECK ( argument IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO sample ( argument ) VALUES ( '{
 "arguments":{
    "app.argument1.appId":["123", "456"],
    "app.argument2.testId":["546", "567"]
 }
}');
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | ARGUMENT                                                                                                                 |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {<br> "arguments":{<br>    "app.argument1.appId":["123", "456"],<br>    "app.argument2.testId":["546", "567"]<br> }<br>} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=346fab174120d75630cdcb7922d4abe3)*

---

> Do you know a way to do this in 12.1?

You could also use `EXISTS` with a correlated `JSON_TABLE` ([which is available from Oracle 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973)).:

```sql
select *
from   sample
where  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           argument,
           '$.arguments."app.argument1.appId"[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$'
           )
         )
  WHERE  value = '123'
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4da4f0de35bd700feebfa2101cdeb33f)*

Comment: I had already tried this query. I just found out this syntax is supported from 12.2 and I'm running Oracle 12.1. Do you know a way to do this in 12.1?

Comment: @rishi Updated. If you are using 12.1.0.2 then you can use `JSON_TABLE`.